# activeMq-5.13.3 setup configurations for wildfly 10.0.0

Tags: activemq-classic, configurationsection

Hi I am new to work on activemq, i am trying to access the messages send from the activemq in mdb onMsg() method but i am unable to get the things done here the sample standalone-full.xml configuration.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">

                <jms-queue name="favouritesQueue" entries="queue/favouritesQueue"/>

            </server>
        </subsystem>
mdb configuration
<mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="activemq-ra.rar"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>


 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:4.0">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="activemq-ra.rar">
                    <archive>
                        activemq-rar-5.13.3.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <config-property name="ServerUrl">
                        tcp://localhost:61616
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="UserName">
                        admin
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="UseInboundSession">
                        false
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="Password">
                        admin
                    </config-property>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">
                            <xa-pool>
                                <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                                <prefill>false</prefill>
                                <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                            </xa-pool>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                    <admin-objects>
                        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="queue/favouritesQueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="favouritesQueue">
                            <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                                queue/favouritesQueue
                            </config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                    </admin-objects>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
```